# How to get other member's profile details from linkedin api

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch users details from linkedIn api. After generating accesstoken I can get my details from linkedIn api but I want to get other members details. How to get this work? please help me.

I have tried the solutions according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?view=li-lms-2022-07#people).
As per the documentation we have to sent a get request to the `GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/people/(id:{person ID})` to Retrieve Other Member's Profile. When I am sending the get request it is showing me

```
data: {
      code: 'VERSION_MISSING',
      message: 'A version must be present. Please specify a version by adding the LinkedIn-Version header.'
    }
```

this error. after searching the documentation I found that there is a note saying

> in order to make the sample calls above succeed, you must include
> X-RestLi-Protocol-Version:2.0.0 in your request header.

I have added that to and still getting the error.

Answer (score 8):

I experienced the same issue. After some browsing this works for me:

Use `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me` instead of `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/me`

Comment: As the [Linkedin docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/versioning?trk=eml-mktg-cust-202302-global-unversioned-legacy-content-apis-sunset-reminder-en&mcid=7024756634421768192&src=e-eml&view=li-lms-unversioned) say, in the end of Feb 2023, the APIs base path will be completely moved from "v2" to "rest". That means, using the old path will not help us anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the version number like this: `LinkedIn-Version: 202210`. It worked for me without changing `/rest` to `/v2`. More info here: [Introducing API Versioning and New Content APIs](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/news/featured-updates/versioning-content-launch).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

As the error says, I tried using `LinkedIn-Version` as the header key and got:

```
{
    "code": "INVALID_VERSION",
    "message": "API versions should have date format as YYYYMM or YYYYMM.RR where RR is the revision"
}
```

With the header value being: 2.0.0

[image: Request example picture]

So I tried sending as value: 202201.01 ==> YYYY=2022, MM=01, RR=01

- YYYY: year
- MM: month
- RR: revision

[image: Request with new value example picture]

Obtaining:

```
{
    "code": "NONEXISTENT_VERSION",
    "message": "Requested version 20220101 is not active"
}
```

Trying some different dates and revision codes, I got to value = 202204.01 that gave me:

```
{
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
"message": "Not enough permissions to access: me.GET.20220401"
}
```

Comment: To Reviewers: "Still no answer to the question, and you have the same problem? Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next person has more to go on." (from [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same issue but you can use this
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me
and it will work

Comment: This has already been suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73430045/10871073).

Answer (score 0):

This version worked for me: 202204.01

Then I got:
"code": "EMPTY_ACCESS_TOKEN",
"message": "Empty oauth2 access token"

Which I think can be fixed by getting the access token by implementing the 3-legged OAuth. I have successfully implemented that for getting someone's profile but I am doing this for getting org info